# Correct Type for onClick handler with multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have my original function

```
const handleClick: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement> = e => {
  e.stopPropagation();
};
```

I needed to pass multiple parameters so I changed it to the following

```
const handleClick: any = (send: boolean) => (e: any) => {
  console.log('send', send);
  e.stopPropagation();
};
```

What should I replace the first and second any with for typescript?

Comment: Replace the first with the type of the function: `(send: boolean) => React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>`, as for the second, you shouldn't even need to type `e` because it should be given by the mouse event handler type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as kelly pointed out, all I had to do was the following

```
const handleClick: (send: boolean) => React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement> = send => e => {
  console.log('send', send);
  e.stopPropagation();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
const newFun = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>,send:boolean) => {
console.log(event.target);
console.log(event.currentTarget);
event.stopPropagation();
}




const handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) =>  newFun(event,true);
```